# xslt for-each loop with multiple entities

Tags: xml, xslt

my input xml is as follows:

```
<xml>
    <Header1>text</Header1>
    <Header2>text</Header2>
    <Header3>text</Header3>
    <Name1>name</Name1>
    <Weight1>100</Weight1>
    <Size1>10</Size1>
    <Name2>name</Name2>
    <Weight2>100</Weight2>
    <Size2>10</Size2>
    <Name3>name</Name3>
    <Weight3>100</Weight3>
    <Size3>10</Size3>
</xml>
```

and my output xml shall be as follows:

```
<xml>
    <Header1>text</Header1>
    <Header2>text</Header2>
    <Header3>text</Header3>
    <SubData1>
        <Name>name</Name>
        <Weight>100</Weight>
        <Size>10</Size>
    </SubData1>
    <SubData2>
        <Name>name</Name>
        <Weight>100</Weight>
        <Size>10</Size>
    </SubData2>
    <SubData3>
        <Name>name</Name>
        <Weight>100</Weight>
        <Size>10</Size>
    </SubData3>

</xml>
```

My issue is that the number of "subdata" nodes can vary, so I was thinking to create a for-each loop in my xslt file but unfortunately it didn't work. Also I need some sort of wildcard to select the proper sub-nodes of each subdata.

Can someone help pleae?

Comment: What do you know for sure? In your example, each subdata has exactly 3 elements in fixed order, so you could easily use that. Or you could count the nodes whose name starts with "Header". Or you could create a `Subdata` group for each element whose name starts with "Name".

Comment: If your XML elements are not called `<header1>` through `<headerN>`, don't name them like this here. Counted element names make it *a lot* harder to write good XSLT code for, so don't use such names just for the example's sake.

Comment: Yes, this is a really poor XML design. But of course sometimes the reason for using XSLT is to turn poorly designed XML into well designed XML.

Comment: You haven't said which version of XSLT you are using. This is a grouping problem, so it's going to be much easier using XSLT 2.0+.